# hidden Div content shown only for new tab

Tags: javascript, html

i have a code that shown hidden content in both old tab and new tab. but i want to show hidden div content in a new tab, not old tab. can you please help me out. 
HTML:

```
<div id="pass" hidden>pass this to the new window</div>
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()">click</a>
```

Java Script:

```
function openWin() {
        var x = document.getElementById("pass");
    x.style.display = "block";     
    var divText = document.getElementById("pass").outerHTML;
    var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
    var doc = myWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(divText);
    doc.close();
}
```